# Как сделать чекбокс обязательным

Tags: php, веб-программирование

есть чекбокс. хотелось бы что бы без его подтверждения не работала кнопка "отправить". подскажите пожалуйста(в гугле смотрел). желательно с помощью php.

Comment: у чекбокса есть свойство `required`. А если хотите конкретно на `PHP`, то поймите что `PHP` это серверная часть, а отображение кнопки клиентская... так что сервером вы никак не повлияете на сценарии у клиента. Единственное что вы можете сделать сервером, это поставить проверку мол если чекбокс не пришел(значит не был отмечен), то выдать соответствующую ошибку.

Comment: спасибо что разъяснили, а не подскажите как это сделать на JS